# 'grabbing' local variables without a return

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not entirely certain how to word it, but I'll explain what I'm looking to do.

```
def function(self):
    x = "x"
    y = "y"
    z = "z"
```

By creating this function as a unique object of a class I should be allocating memory to the variables themselves. How, at the time of creation of the class object and calling this function, can I get the variables directly from this function?

(i.e. `class.function.x`)

I'm not asking for `return` syntax, I want direct memory mapping (or calling) of this variable without returning a value.

Comment: As far as I know you can't - that is the point of a return. If you want them to be accessed by other methods on the same class - you can make new attributes of that class : ''self.x = "x"'', but once the function/method ends then the local variables dissapear

Comment: @Tony Suffolk 66 The point is direct memory mapping without segment faults, not make localized variables. I need the pointers, C pointers, at least as a start.

Comment: so use mmap - and actually directly allocate the memory.  As the answers have given you - there is no direct way to access the memory of a local variable from outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

No. The scope is destroyed when the function returns, and all local variables along with it.

Comment: when it returns, yes, but what about at runtime?

Comment: @NationWidePants: ... It returns during runtime, so I don't know what you're getting at.

Comment: Once the object (,object being the function called, in this case,) is created it instantiates the variables on a stack. Where'(s/re) the pointer(s)? Certainly not a trivial question, and not one most people ask since I doubt it's considered 'pythonic' to do or ask such a thing.

Comment: There is no "stack" in Python, only the scope. And the variables don't exist until the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that those variables are instantiated until the function is run, and go out of scope when the functions returns. As posted I do not think what you want is possible (happy to be corrected).

However you can do,

```
class A(object):
    def f(self):
        pass
A.f.b = 42
```

when you make your class. Then later `A.f.b` is accessible.

Answer (score 1):

A basic method only remembers symbols, binding occurs upon invocation.

#### Python bindings 101

A class can bind variable, and so can an instance (object), and method invocation can change the instance and class variables.

http://ideone.com/KkzhRk

```
class Binder(object):
    x = "x"
    y = "y"
    z = "z"

    def f1(self):
        self.x = "xx"
        self.y = "yx"
        self.z = "zx"

    def f2(self):
        Binder.x = "xx"
        Binder.y = "yx"
        Binder.z = "zx"

binder = Binder()

print(Binder.x)  # class access
print(Binder.y)  # class access
print(Binder.z)  # class access
print(binder.x)  # instance access
print(binder.y)  # instance access
print(binder.z)  # instance access

binder.f1()

print(Binder.x)  # class access
print(Binder.y)  # class access
print(Binder.z)  # class access
print(binder.x)  # instance access
print(binder.y)  # instance access
print(binder.z)  # instance access

binder.f2()

print(Binder.x)  # class access
print(Binder.y)  # class access
print(Binder.z)  # class access
print(binder.x)  # instance access
print(binder.y)  # instance access
print(binder.z)  # instance access
```

There is also the topic of closures – nested method binding the values of the enclosing method.

http://ideone.com/bBnUJG

```
def mkclosure():
    x = "x"
    y = "y"
    z = "z"

    def closure():
        # Need to reference them for the closure to be created.
        return (x, y, z)

    return closure

function = mkclosure()

for cell in function.__closure__:
    print(cell.cell_contents)
```